# using .delegate to animate image siblings using mouseenter or mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .delegate to fade the opacity of the selected image siblings, I have written an if statement that determines whether the  event type is mouseover or mouseenter then performs the animate. My problem is the || as Im not sure how I can actually write the if so that it works?

```
$('#holder').delegate('#holder > .img', 'hover', function(e) {
            var $image = $(this);
            var $imageSiblings = $image.siblings();

            if(e.type === 'mouseenter || mouseover') {
                $imageSiblings.stop().animate({ 'opacity' : 0.8 }, 200);
            } else {
                $imageSiblings.stop().animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 200);
            }

            console.log(e.type);

        });
```

It would be great if someone could advise me of the best method to achieve the effect

Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(e.type === 'mouseenter' || e.type === 'mouseover') {
```

Actually the event type will never be `mouseover`. `hover` binds to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` only.

You might want to do this:

```
$('#holder').delegate('#holder > .img', 'mouseenter mouseover', function(e) {
     $(this).siblings().stop().animate({ 'opacity' : 0.8 }, 200);
}).delegate('#holder > .img', 'mouseleave', function(e) {
     $(this).siblings().stop().animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 200);
});
```

But I think you don't even need `mouseover` here.

Comment: thanks for this, the reason I want to add in mouseover is because when i log out the type one moment im getting mouseenter then the next im getting mouseover?

Comment: @kyllle: I don't know why you get this, but the code above should help you anyways.